# Kotlin Coroutines run all operation on the same Thread

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am using the V8 JavaScript engine in my app. It enforces that all operations executed on the same thread that it was initialised on.

I have introduces a `CoroutineContext` out of a `HandlerThread` using `asCoroutineDispatcher()` extension

Using that context, for every function I do:

```
suspend fun executeRandomCode() = withContext(jsContext) {

    // run desired V8 code

}
```

So my question is, if i run the following code:

```
ioScope.launch {

    executeRandomCode()
    executeRandomCode2()
    executeRandomCode3()
}
```

Is there any overhead of doing multiple function calls where each function does `withContext(jsContext)`?

Is there a better way to enforce single thread using coroutines?

Comment: Why launch in the `ioScope` when you keep switching back to `jsContext`? Your whole `launch` block could run on the `jsContext`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Because inside this scope I do other operations that requires to also be off the main thread

Comment: If you have a sequence of main-thread ops, you can wrap them in an outside `withContext(jsContext)`, this will reduce context switching. You can also consider inverting the contexts and use `withContext(ioContext)` around the blocking ops.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can the `jsContext` that is attached to a `HandlerThread` inside the class that encapsulates V8 usages be exposed to outer classes? Then it can be used instead of the ioScope (don't need to run anything in parallel)

Comment: I don't know the JS details here, but you seem to have access to `jsContext`, you can wrap it in a coroutine scope to be used elsewhere.

Comment: I see, so instead of exposing the `jsContext` i expose a `CoroutineScope(jsContext)`

Comment: Yes, and possibly attach a job to it if you want structured concurrency.